# Different HTML files in one PHP file

Tags: php

I searched in the forum for about 2 hours and didn't find a solution for that.

Problem:

I have one PHP file. And I have multiple HTML files.

At first I show the first HTML file when the PHP file is loaded.
So I included the code from "page1.html" into the PHP file.

Now after clicking the submit button and the validation on this PHP file I want to replace the current HTML file with another one.

But when I include page2.html after the validation was successful, it shows just the body content of the page2.html file under the "page1.html" content.

I want to replace the entire html file, not just a few elements. And it has to be in the PHP file where the first file was included too.

Is there any solution?

```
<?php



include 'page1.html';


// define variables and initialize with empty values

$Content "";
$Error = "";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
    if (!isset($_POST["name"]))
        {
        $Error = "There is an error.";
        }
      else
         {
        $Content = $_POST["content"];
        }


    if (empty($Error))
        {

        include 'page2.html';


        }
    }

?>
```

Comment: Can't you use `include "whatever.html"`?

Comment: Can you post some code? You will need to prevent page1.html loading when your validation is successful. The way you detect validation should be used to decide whether or not to load page1.html or page2.html

Comment: Could you demonstrate code sample?

Comment: The thing is, that I included the page1.html file before the validation, because the validation is based on that file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use condition in your `PHP` file

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST))
{
    include 'page2.html';
}
else
{
    include 'page1.html';
}
```

Comment: After the first visit the page1.html file is already included. And when I include the page2.html file afterwards, then there are both files.

Answer (score 1):

Once the user has clicked submit on page1.html a form is sent to the server to be validated by the php file. Assuming that validation is successful you can redirect the browser to page2.html using `header("Location:page2.html");` which will set the location in the response headers to page2.html.

Comment: No. It has to be within the PHP file.

Comment: I don't understand why it would need to be in the same PHP file. Please elaborate.